# SQL Server timestamp convert to date

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server one of the table, date column of datatype `timestamp` showing `0x0000000004C05C6E`,I want to convert to date format. Can anyone help me to brief about this timestamp?

Comment: try SELECT cast(columnname as datetime) example: SELECT cast(cast(cast('2011-01-01' as datetime) as timestamp) as datetime)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server's `TIMESTAMP` datatype has **nothing** to do with a date and time.

It's just a binary representation of a consecutive number - it's only good for making sure a row hasn't change since it's been read.

In never versions of SQL Server, it's being called `RowVersion` - since that's really what it is. See the [MSDN docs on ROWVERSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx):

> *Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. rowversion is generally used as a mechanism
>   for version-stamping table rows. The
>   rowversion data type is **just an incrementing number and does not
>   preserve a date or a time**. To record a date or time, use a datetime2
>   data type.*

So you **cannot** convert a SQL Server `TIMESTAMP` to a date/time - it's just not a date/time.